# openvpn easy-rsa command not found

Tags: rsa, openvpn, centos6

im trying to install openvpn on my centos 6 box
im using epel repository to install the vpn
all went fine on the installation but somehow when coming to generate certificate part
lots of command not found raised when im typing "source ./vars" command

here is returned from the terminal

```
[root@... easy-rsa]# source ./vars
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
NOTE: If you run ./clean-all, I will be doing a rm -rf on /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
```

here is my vars file setting

```
# easy-rsa parameter settings

# NOTE: If you installed from an RPM,
# don't edit this file in place in
# /usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa --
# instead, you should copy the whole
# easy-rsa directory to another location
# (such as /etc/openvpn) so that your
# edits will not be wiped out by a future
# OpenVPN package upgrade.

# This variable should point to
# the top level of the easy-rsa
# tree.
export EASY_RSA="`pwd`"

#
# This variable should point to
# the requested executables
#
export OPENSSL="openssl"
export PKCS11TOOL="pkcs11-tool"
export GREP="grep"


# This variable should point to
# the openssl.cnf file included
# with easy-rsa.
export KEY_CONFIG=/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/openssl.cnf

# Edit this variable to point to
# your soon-to-be-created key
# directory.
#
# WARNING: clean-all will do
# a rm -rf on this directory
# so make sure you define
# it correctly!
export KEY_DIR="$EASY_RSA/keys"

# Issue rm -rf warning
echo NOTE: If you run ./clean-all, I will be doing a rm -rf on $KEY_DIR

# PKCS11 fixes
export PKCS11_MODULE_PATH="dummy"
export PKCS11_PIN="dummy"

# Increase this to 2048 if you
# are paranoid.  This will slow
# down TLS negotiation performance
# as well as the one-time DH parms
# generation process.
export KEY_SIZE=1024

# In how many days should the root CA key expire?
export CA_EXPIRE=3650

# In how many days should certificates expire?
export KEY_EXPIRE=3650

# These are the default values for fields
# which will be placed in the certificate.
# Don't leave any of these fields blank.
export KEY_COUNTRY="US"
export KEY_PROVINCE="CA"
export KEY_CITY="SanFrancisco"
export KEY_ORG="Fort-Funston"
export KEY_EMAIL="me@myhost.mydomain"
export KEY_EMAIL=mail@host.domain
export KEY_CN=changeme
export KEY_NAME=changeme
export KEY_OU=changeme
export PKCS11_MODULE_PATH=changeme
export PKCS11_PIN=1234
```

any help will be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice there are 7 command not found statements before the echo. There are also 7 "empty" lines before the echo. It appears that the key dir variable is properly expanding in the echo statement. After the echo statement there are 5 "empty" lines and 5 more command not found errors. This makes me think that the command not found statements are a result of the "empty" lines.

Obviously if the line is empty it shouldn't cause that sort of an error. How did the "vars" file get there? Did you copy/paste it and invisible characters got copied in the process? Or perhaps it was edited on a device that used a different type of carriage returns?

You should use an editor such as vim on it which will help you see normally hidden characters. You could also try to use a program like tofrodos to convert the carriage returns. When you source a file you are actually executing a script and any variables exported become part of our shell that sourced it in. Normally scripts would conform to unix line endings.

Comment: its copied with this command cp -rf /usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/* /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa

i tried remove the empty line now its working :) thanks for pointing it out